# How to import graphml file using inputstream in tinkerpop 3.4

Tags: import, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

With tinkerpop 3.3.3 I was able to load the graphml as below

```
try (final InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("graph.xml")) {
    graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).reader().create().readGraph(stream, newGraph);
}
```

But tinkerpop 3.4 has deprecated `graph.io()` method and provided `GraphTraversalSource#io(String)`.

```
graph.traversal().io('graph.xml').read().iterate()
```

The problem with this method is that I'm not able to pass the inputstream since only filename string is supported. Because of which I'm not able to import a file present inside jar classpath.

Anybody knows the correct way to import graphml from application classpath in tinkerpop 3.4 apis

Answer (score 0):

TinkerPop documentation clearly states following:

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/IoCore.html

"Notice GraphTraversalSource.io(String) doesn't support read operation from java.io.InputStream or write operation to java.io.OutputStream. Thus for readers or writers which need this functionality are safe to use this deprecated method. There is no intention to remove this method unless all the functionality is replaced by the io step of GraphTraversalSource."

So if you are using streams, it is ok to continue using IoCore.